# How to load all .properties files in an application, starting at a certain package?

Tags: java, resources, properties, classpath

I would like to load all all .properties files starting at a certain package level.  All in that package and any child packages should be loaded.  So for example if I specified my.foo as the starting package, my.foo.MyProperties.properties and my.foo.bar.MyOtherProperties.properties should be picked up.  I would prefer (and will accept) a solution that uses the classpath and went into all available .jars, but I will upvote a file based solution as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/).  The code should be something like,

```
    Predicate<String> filter = new FilterBuilder().include(".*\\.properties");
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .filterInputsBy(filter)
            .setScanners(new ResourcesScanner())
            .setUrls(asList(ClasspathHelper.forJavaClassPath())));
    System.out.println(reflections.getStore().get(ResourcesScanner.class).keySet());
```

Look at the [test code](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/source/browse/trunk/reflections/src/test/java/org/reflections/ReflectionsTest.java) for more examples.